# Need query to retrieve most recent data but also groupby

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am not able to create query which gives me results of both group by and recent record.

my member table is like this

```
ID PlotID Requirement DateTime
1   G23     text1      2016.08.10 10.10.10
2   G23     text2      2016.08.10 12.12.12
3   B11     text3      2016.08.10 4.5.6
4   G23     text4      2016.08.10 12.16.16
```

I want to display in my report as group by `PlotIC` but most recent record

Output should be

```
G23  text4 2016.08.10 12.16.16
B11  text3 2016.08.10 4.5.6

Select * from member group by plotid order by datetime
```

This is not resulting as what I want output. It always gives me first record of `G23` but not latest record of `G23`.

Can you give right query?

Comment: what datatype is DateTime. That looks like data from Mars

Answer (score 0):

Your existing query only works because `mysql` allows you to include columns in your `select` statement that aren't in your `group by`.  However, the columns returned for that grouping are arbitrary.

Here's one option using a `join` with a subquery and `max`:

```
select m.id, m.plotid, m.requirement, m.datetime
from member m
  join (select plotid, max(datetime) maxdatetime
        from member
        group by plotid) m2 on m.plotid = m2.plotid
                     and m.datetime = m2.maxdatetime
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e06006/3)

---

And another using `exists`:

```
select m.id, m.plotid, m.requirement, m.datetime
from member m
where exists (
  select 1
  from member m2
  where m.plotid = m2.plotid
  having max(m2.datetime) = m.datetime
  )
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e06006/4)

Answer (score 0):

Because GROUP BY has strange responses with string values like that really weird 'DateTime' try this

```
SELECT mr1.* FROM member mr1 JOIN 
(SELECT PlotID,MAX(ID) Id2 FROM Member GROUP BY PlotID) mr2 
ON mr.ID=mr2.Id2
```

This should give what you want
The inner select gives you all the last Ids for each PlotID and the first SELECT gives you all the data for just those IDs

Answer (score 0):

using the Max() function:

```
select PlotID,Requirement,Max(DateTime) from member group by PlotID;
```

and I have take a try:

```
mysql> DESC member;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| ID          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Plotid      | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Requirement | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Datetime    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM member;
+----+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| ID | Plotid | Requirement | Datetime            |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------------+
|  1 | G23    | text1       | 2016-08-10 10:10:10 |
|  2 | G23    | text2       | 2016-08-10 12:12:12 |
|  3 | G11    | text3       | 2016-08-10 04:05:06 |
|  4 | G23    | text4       | 2016-08-10 12:16:16 |
+----+--------+-------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT Plotid,Requirement,Max(Datetime) FROM member GROUP BY Plotid;
+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| Plotid | Requirement | Max(Datetime)       |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| G11    | text3       | 2016-08-10 04:05:06 |
| G23    | text1       | 2016-08-10 12:16:16 |
+--------+-------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: infact date column came empty after this

Comment: I made a mistake in spelling "member".

Answer (score 0):

select PlotID,Requirement,Max(DateTime) from nember group by PlotID;

above query will give you error because requirement field is not used in group by clause also not any aggregate function like sum,count etc.

Try this....

```
SELECT Gr.Id,m.Requirement,Gr.DateTime FROM member m 
JOIN 
(SELECT PlotID,MAX(ID) Id FROM Member GROUP BY PlotID)Gr 
ON m.ID = Gr.Id
```